# $e^{17 + ln(7x)}$ - I'm stuck on this problem. I could really use some help

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms

I know that the $\ln{(7x)}$ will go to just $7x$, but I'm confused about how the $17$ fits into the answer.

Comment: $x^{a+b}=x^ax^b$

Comment: You didn't say what the problem statement was. How can anyone help you if they don't know what exactly it is that you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

$$e^{17+\ln 7x} = e^{17} e^{ \ln 7x} = 7xe^{17}$$

And it does not simplify any more.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean $e^{17+\ln(7x)}$ and you want to simplify?

You can use the following:

$e^{a+b} = e^ae^b$

$e^{\ln(x)}=x$